# Is "You’re a better man than I am, Gunga Din!" still considered a compliment in English?

Tags: contemporary-english

I grew up hearing the phrase, "You’re a better man than I am, Gunga Din!" used as a compliment, a genuine expression of admiration, fairly self-effacing at the same time.

I have to admit that, while I knew from context that it was meant as praise, I long ago forgot most of the [poem it came from](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/46783#poem), remembering just that Gunga Din was heroic on the battlefield. Hence the admiration.

I was about to use the phrase when I realized that the person I was addressing might be too young to get the reference, so I skipped it, but went back to read the poem. It is (to me) shockingly racist, with lines like

> An’ for all ’is dirty ’ide
>   ’E was white, clear white, inside
>   When ’e went to tend the wounded under fire!

Researching it a bit, it seems the poem is not taught anymore, much like some of Mark Twain’s works in the US.

So, is it still a compliment or have the racist overtones made it obsolete?

**Edited to add**: The last stanza refers to meeting up with Gunga Din in hell someday. [**Again edited to add**] I realize that the meeting in hell was a compliment - once again - to Gunga Din. The author calls him, "You *Lazarushian*-leather Gunga Din!" In the Bible, the Rich man (in hell) asks to let Lazarus (in heaven) give him water: ‘Father Abraham, have pity on me and send Lazarus to dip the tip of his finger in water and cool my tongue, because I am in agony in this fire.’ While the Biblical answer is 'Nope', the author has so much faith in the goodness of Gunga Din that he believes Gunga Din will bring him - and others - water not only on the battlefield, but also in hell. (I think...) Thanks to @Michael.

<sub>Sorry, I realize this has some POB aspects to it.</sub>

Comment: Never heard of it in 5+ decades as a native speaker of American English.

Comment: I know the poem, since I rather like Kipling but having just been rewatching Rosemary and Thyme, a 2003-2007 mystery series (from ITV?), I noticed it being used by Laura Thyme in what I take to be it's usual meaning, i.e. I wouldn't have guts/gall/moral fiber to do that, but I admire that you do. Thought it would be worth noting, since this was a rather main stream detective series.

Comment: The extremely short answer to this is that whatever compliment is intended might be overshadowed by negative concerns of association with colonialism.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in addition of listed above this quote was used in many other contexts. I'd even argue most people won't even know that it is Kipling quote, not even speaking about any assumed "racism" associated with it.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

It's a cardinal error to confuse a depiction of bigotry with bigotry itself.

Yes, the narrator of the poem is racist, not only by modern standards but in the opinion of the author of the poem.  The juxtaposition of the disdainful attitude of the soldier with his candid admission that the blackfaced heathen slavey whom he beats and abuses is, in fact, the braver, better man gives the poem its power.

> You Lazarushian-leather Gunga Din!
>   Though I’ve belted you and flayed you,
>   By the livin’ Gawd that made you,
>   You’re a better man than I am, Gunga Din!

Comment: I could not agree more with your first sentence. I think the poem is very well written, and, like Twain... baby with the bathwater kind of stuff. Thanks!

Comment: @anongoodnurse -- I was thinking of Eminem and Andrew Dice Clay, but Twain is a much better example.

Comment: However... "Mighty white of you", a compliment in the US, was not understood to be racist 60 years ago, so. It's still somewhat unanswered for me. You seem to understand it as I do/did. Are we right? Is it semi-ironic in that he's telling this to a man he'll meet in hell? It this too much of a 'fighting man thing' for me? I don't know.

Comment: When I was a kid, "mighty white of you" could only be used sarcastically, to indicate I thought whatever you did was done in a patronizing and disdainful spirit.  God knows how people would take the expression today.  Fortunately, the Gunga-din reference requires the person to be reasonably literate, and so, at least in theory, understanding of nuance.  That said, I was once on a corner in Hyderabad and my local friend rushed unafraid through traffic.  I only got as far as "You're a better man than I" before realizing he might not appreciate the reference, if he understood it at all.

Comment: Gosh, now I have to look that up, too!

Comment: @anongoodnurse -- "disdainful"?  "Hyderabad"?

Comment: Lol at your story! No, "mighty white of you".

Comment: 40 years ago in the South, "mighty white of you" was used just as unconsciously (by white people, of course) as "Jew you down".  Where I live, they both faded quickly in the mid to late 1980s.

Comment: I've never heard "might white of you", before, and if I heard it now, I'd hear it as racist. I'm not sure how else one could interpret it, unless it were not meant as a compliment.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: "mighty" as in "very".  You will still hear this in the rural south U.S.

Comment: At the end of "Oh Brother where art thou", George Clooney forgives John Turturro's character and he responds.. "Thats mighty white of you, Everett",

Comment: It's like this conversation is on another place of reality :)  Note that, in the USA, you **cannot use the word niggardly** (in schools and so on) because of confusion with the unrelated vulgar term which has similar spelling.  The idea of quoting or using (what is now just an utterly obscure) racist poem by a racist, is a non-starter.

Comment: @Fattie - "Utterly obscure"? I don't think it's quite that bad...

Comment: I think you have a good heart regarding the literacy of the English-speaking world today  :)  I think Chris below sort of hit the nail on the head; you'd either just be "A Racist" ("mentioned Kipling") or more likely blank-faced as a dinosaur making references to ancient texts ..  :)

Comment: "It's a cardinal error to confuse a depiction of bigotry with bigotry itself." Except that Kipling's thinking and views are well documented elsewhere. He *was* a racist and a bigot. Maybe a talented one, but one nonetheless. And he came from a racist and bigoted culture (Imperial Britain) so I don't think is worth dwelling upon either.

Comment: @FaheemMitha -- find a historical figure from more than, oh, 75 years ago, whose bigotry and racism are _not_ "well documented".  Look at Gandhi, Lincoln, anybody you want. And any culture anywhere ever that couldn't be fairly described as "racist and bigoted".  It is unjust and unreasonable to take a work that is about the moral virtue of a non-white person, extract a quote from it where a previously bigoted (white) character acknowledges that virtue, and then complain about racism, just because the author did not completely transcend his times.

Comment: It's a cardinal error to assume everyone will read a work the same way, though -- or to assume that someone who references a work naturally agrees with all the themes and beliefs it communicates. For example, some fans of the film _Fight Club_ think the titular activity is awesome, while others regard the whole movie as a criticism of violent masculinity; and then there are many, many people who just half-remember a famous quote or two and little else about the overall context.

Comment: @AlexP -- true, but what can one do with that fact?  Would you give up quoting [Twain](http://www.latimes.com/nation/nationnow/la-na-nn-mark-twain-racism-20140519-story.html) because of accusations of racism?  [Mencken](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/opinions/1990/01/12/mencken-just-plain-antisemitism/2e4272e6-dadd-411b-aa3d-0c601c165023/)? [Lincoln](https://artsbeat.blogs.nytimes.com/2008/12/10/abraham-lincoln-racist/)? [Gandhi](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-34265882)?

Comment: I wouldn't give up quoting *Twain* —but I wouldn't quote his lines about Injun Joe without a very compelling reason and a pretty good idea of my audience's likely understanding of the line.

Comment: @Malvolio Step back from the question of Kipling's character and ask yourself: what does this sentence communicate? Some quotations are essentially aphorisms, pithy thesis statements mined out of a larger work specifically because they stand well on their own ("Whenever the human race assembles to a number exceeding four, it cannot stand free speech"); others are deeply referential, relying on shared cultural context to communicate anything at all ("Aren't you a little short for a Stormtrooper?"). The latter variety can easily become meaningless catchphrases as the shared context is forgotten.

Comment: @Malvolio How does "blackfaced" come into this, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin — it’s from the poem itself, referring to people who are naturally dark-skinned, not any sort of masquerade.

Comment: @Malvolio Thanks and sorry; I was sidetracked by a wholly different conversation about theatrical blackface

Comment: Right. Partly you need to look at the poem in the context of it's time. But, in it's clumsy way, it's giving Gunga Din the most sincere compliment he could, "you're white inside"! The soldier is making the statement, clumsily, that the colour of Gunga's skin doesn't stop him from being a better man than he is, a hero and a great man.

To be given, not just a consolatory "well done there for an Indian", but a full-blood complement "you're as good as any white man and better than some" is an anti-racist notion. In it's context, but there's no point criticising dead Victorians for being racist.

Answer (score 44):

Given that a few, presumably well-read, people here have different recollections of the poem, and different interpretations, you would be unwise to make assumptions as to the effect on your audience. Many people's reaction would be along the lines of “you what?” having never heard the quote and not even recognising it as a quote, never mind a poem or Kipling.

Those of us who studied it in the dim and distant past may remember racism in the context — but not in detail. We may remember (if we’ve read a little on the subject) that Kipling’s views are the subject of much discussion. My understanding is that while racist by today’s standards he was unusually progressive by the standards of his time in at least some aspects of his treatment of the natives.

At best, quoting Kipling will seem old-fashioned (with the possible exception of “If—”) . So I suggest you only use the quote if you don’t mind people thinking you’re a (possibly racist) dinosaur. If I were in the audience, I would give the speaker the benefit of the doubt, but that’s about me, not the quote.

Finally, although the narrator is expressing admiration (even without the racial aspects we can’t ignore) it boils down to “for someone who’s my subordinate, you’re a better man than I am”. After all, the narrator had the right to beat Gunga Din. This may not be the impression you want to give.

Comment: Thanks for addressing my question directly. It's refreshing and helpful. It can boil down to that (which is why I was shocked on rereading it), or it can boil down to, "for someone who's *supposed to be my subordinate*, I realize at last that you're not; in fact, you're a better man than ever I am  (Gunga Din). But you're right in much of what you say, and I certainly am a dinosaur, so, again, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @anongoodnurse regarding the assertion in the above answer *it boils down to “for someone who’s my subordinate, you’re a better man than I am”* I am inclined to agree with you that the narrator is not making a qualified or condescending statement,  but (by the end of it) acknowledging frankly and unequivocally that 'I may be the white man and you may be the native, but *you are by far the better man*, Gunga Din!'

Comment: @EnglishStudent - Agreed.

Comment: I'm missing the reference for (with the possible exception of "If--")

Comment: @Mr.Mindor Kipling's poem ["If---"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/46473) is still widely quoted (and misquoted).  I've seen it on mugs and tea towels.

Comment: Oh that is the actual title, I assumed you were oddly truncating or censoring some commonly known work. One of those moments where a few seconds of googling could have given me the answer. Thank's Chris.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor It's not obivous if you haven't come across it before, and searching on the title alone isn't much use.

Comment: You can just say "You're a better man than I (am)," though, and avoid the racism issue. IMO that part has become a catchphrase of its own, so it won't be an obsolete reference either.

Answer (score 36):

My dad (native to Oklahoma) uses it, and I picked up the usage from him. I believe I've heard my mother-in-law (native to Ohio) use it as well.

The way we use it **isn't a compliment**. Its more an observation that the person in question is undergoing a lot of (potentially hazardous) work for no really good reward. It would be used in a lot of the same contexts as "Have fun storming the castle!" (Princess Bride callback), "Good luck with *that*", or "Better you than me."

Comment: "Better you that me." Yes, it does have that connotation as well, now that you mention it. Thanks!

Comment: @anongoodnurse - To be perfectly honest, this is the first time I've seen the poem. I always figured the phrase was from an old movie or something.... (upvoted the question for teaching me something)

Comment: Yep ... I used to hear the Gunga Din line sometimes used in that sort of context when I was a kid (more or less nearly half a century ago and in a different country to you) but wouldn't use it now (the only time I refer to the poem at all is if I get locked out of somewhere ... as in "Hey I'm locked out and I *Gunga Din*!"). But I have used the Princess Bride quote, especially with my kids; it's usually understood even by people who haven't seen the movie.

Comment: I've picked up the usage in the exact same way, my dad coming from Virginia, though

Answer (score 34):

Many thanks for directing my attention to this intriguing and controversial poem from one of the Children of Empire.

> "A racist would not have glorified Gunga Din in the way Kipling did," wrote Andrew Roberts in The Telegraph on 13 May 2003

http://www.telegraph.co.uk/comment/personal-view/3591241/At-last-Kipling-is-saved-from-the-ravages-of-political-correctness.html

and having read the full text of Kipling's famous poem, I fully agree with him, Indian that I am and a long time reader of Literature!

It is well known that Kipling had great love for India **and** for Empire. Lines taken in isolation may paint a nasty picture, but each poem should be read in its entirety, in context, and I am convinced there is nothing inherently racist about 'Gunga Din'.

It is amazing to see that Kipling and Mark Twain have become controversial -- are their opponents even reading their works before donning the armor of righteous indignation to do battle against the ghosts of two great humanists! In fact **that** is the bigotry of ignorance, absolutely incapable of recognising oblique sarcasm or self-reflexive irony, and it shows that nuance is dead!

HOWEVER, you are asking about the statement 'you are a better man than me, Gunga Din!' -- that line is by itself proof that it is not a racist poem, but earnestly politically-correct non-readers who have mentally 'tagged' Gunga Din (possibly without reading it) as a racist work may be vocally offended, especially those of the left-leaning liberals (not all but some) who are unforgiving of all imperialism except the dictatorship of the proletariat, which alone is historically and ideologically justified.

Moreover, as already pointed out in the earlier comments and answers, the vast majority of people just may not get the reference!

Comment: I would suggest (as I suspect others have) that Kipling is better described as nationalist/culturalist rather than racist. He seems to have had no particular animus toward people for their genetic origins. He did have an eye for the foibles of different cultures, but does not seem to have held these differences as immutable. What he was was a firm believer in his own culture, without ascribing imaginary flaws to others. He also understood the price the British Empire paid for its position, particularly in the lives of its young men.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast you are totally right; and Kipling lost his own son to War, as I recall, so he paid as high price as any other citizen of Empire! That makes it doubly harsh and tragic when somebody in this time and age glibly passes judgment without understanding and labels a great work 'racist.'

Comment: Kipling was writer by trade. He described what he saw and heard. In all his writings I never had the distasteful feeling of racist dislike. Quite the opposite, he made me feel for the Indians he described. Think of why the girl in the story can no longer knead her own bread; the bereaved husband in Without Benefit of Clergy; Janee crying in the watercourse. They are heartbreaking.

Comment: You need to be cautious interpreting an opinion piece from a fairly right-wing newspaper -- it's one but y no means the only viewopint.  The use of "saved from the ravages of political correctness" in the title further reinforces this need.  The study of Kipling's views is interesting, and too long to go into here; then you get on to how he expressed them in his work, and whether/how to quote that expression.

Comment: @ChrisH thanks a lot for providing the political background of the newspaper, which was completely unknown to me here in India -- but I am only quoting their opinion as an example of a published piece, and *my independent interpretation* that the 'Gunga Din' poem is not racist is based on my own reading of the entire work *before* looking for published pieces that possibly agree with this point of view. I believe a writer of a previous century is not to be held accountable for anything based on modern concepts of political correctness,  but also agree controversial quotations are best avoided!

Comment: @ChrisH (contd...) To add to my previous comments that people of a bygone era cannot be held accountable for anything by modern standards of political correctness, let me just suggest that the ancient Romans considered themselves superior to any other people on earth, conquering and even enslaving many peoples of Europe, Asia and Africa, but they did it unselfconsciously and with no idea that it was 'wrong' and 'evil' from a modern liberal perspective, so it would be as meaningless to call them 'racist' as to call a lion a 'cruel beast!'

Comment: I disagree with this answer, and most of the comments, but will refrain from a downvote, because at the end of the day it's about a difference of opinion. Kipling *was* a racist. And they're nothing wrong with calling Imperial Romans "racists". They deserve that and harsher names besides. They were a nasty bunch of thugs. And their attitudes persist in the present, particularly in Ango-American imperial racist viewpoints. It's not for nothing that significant aspects of British and US culture are modelled on Rome. (But this is only marginally relevant, so I'll stop.)

Comment: @RedSonja totally right -- I readily agree with you even not having read any Kipling other than Gunga Din, which I read just yesterday -- I have read **of** Kipling and know how he is widely considered a great humanist along with Twain, Victor Hugo, Faulkner, Tolstoi and Dickens. IF I CAN'T write like them and make the world cry and smile like them, then I SHALL NOT judge them! The test of racism by modern liberal ethics should be applied only to recent writers, political leaders and celebrities -- let's spare Anon-of-Old, Mark Twain and Kipling!

Comment: @FaheemMitha many thanks for disagreeing **yet** respecting our right to our opinions and 'refraining from dowvote' which is more than I would expect from a few people here -- in fact I did not say the ancient Romans did *not* deserve to be called racist, but only that the term and its modern sensibilities cannot be very meaningfully applied to people of a bygone age that right upto the 1950's era of decolonisation (and possibly even beyond) believed in the 'twin' doctrines of 'might is right' and 'we know better!'

Comment: I'm in a similar position to @FaheemMitha -- I disagree with your conclusions but don't downvote on that basis. In fact I'm closer to voting up as a helpful contribution to the debate.  There's a fair bit to agree with in the piece you quote -- and a fair bit to disagree with.

Comment: @ChrisH thanks for the support -- I will admit that I have never been even a historical victim of racist prejudice, so cannot really imagine the angst, and personally am very liberal myself, but it is no good attacking long dead writers and ancient cultures when racist politicians, entertainers and ordinary citizens flourish all around us in this very day and age! I shall not drag names into the debate, but the very resurgence of nationalistic politics in many parts of the world is more cause for concern than the bygone, innocent 'imperialism' of Kipling.

Comment: Hi @EnglishStudent. "only that the term and its modern sensibilities cannot be very meaningfully applied to people of a bygone age" I don't see why not, but I guess we should agree to disagree.

Comment: @EnglishStudent I don't know whether this is true, but let's say it is true for the sake of argument. Why is that relevant?

Comment: @FaheemMitha we can indeed agree to disagree, but the reason I say so is because the whole concept of racially ethical behavior was unknown or unimportant in those bygone cultures! How could they strive 'not to be racist' when racism is itself a modern sensibility? That would make them only retrospectively and only in **our** opinion, a 'bunch of thugs' which may well be the judgment of history, but they were acting under the ethics and imperatives of their own times and not ours. What is really important is to fight the racism that we find all around us in this day and age.

Comment: You deserved it! That's all I can say. Wish I could accept more than one answer. :)

Comment: Juxtaposing Kipling and Twain is especially interesting here; they were some of the loudest voices on opposite sides of the "white man's burden."

Comment: @fectin "(...) Kipling and Twain (...) were some of the loudest voices on opposite sides of the "white man's burden" --  you make a very interesting point; and many modern champions of political correctness have indiscriminately labeled **both** of them as racist! Is that illogical or am I missing something?  I shall rest my case by saying that many generations of readers have read and loved Kipling and Twain, and did not accuse their writings of being racist; and I respect and trust the good sense of those readers more than that of politically correct persons who don't love literature.

Comment: @EnglishStudent The answer is complex and I'm not expert. From my limited understanding: In many modern senses, both *were* racists. So what. The divide was more about the proper relation of developed and undeveloped nations. Kipling's take was much more paternalist; roughly: Britain has a duty to drag everyone up to a British standard of life, kicking and screaming if necessary. Twain seems mostly to have objected to the kicking-and-screaming part, but also to have been skeptical of whether draggers would (or could) ever deal fairly, and of their motives.

Comment: @EnglishStudent See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_the_Person_Sitting_in_Darkness

Comment: @fectin very true indeed! The whole debate at the time was how the so called superior nations should 'minister to' the 'uncivilised multitudes' of the rest of the world. What was not widely known was that most of those peoples had a long-lived civilization and complex culture, so as to even (in some cases) consider the same imperialists to be barbarians! My whole point is that we cannot apply modern standards of racism to authors who lived in a bygone age, and moreover, **if** the writer's *literary voice* had any tone of racism it would soon have been detected by generations of world readers!

Comment: @fectin many thanks for the enlightening link. Let me clarify that I agree with your points, but the wider debate on this page has been about (not imperialism but) racism. Kipling and Twain  conveyed their message with satire & irony, but also great humanity. Anybody could feel free to call them racist by our ethics of PC *if they had written those pieces in this day and age,* but they were products of their own times, and yet had more love and honest regard for the people of the world (than most of their peers did) -- their intentions were good and that's why it is unfair to call them racist!

Comment: @EnglishStudent This poem is not taught in India because of racial reasons. How do you know so much about it?

Comment: @Rahul in fact I read the short poem 'Gunga Din' only after reading this original question! Nor I have read much of Kipling's work but I had read the Wikipedia article on Rudyard Kipling 2 years ago and was impressed by his parallel attachment to India and Empire. Moreover I have been reading fiction for 33 of my (soon to be) 38 years and am confident of detecting a writer's **tone** or *literary voice*, so I don't depend on other people's judgment of what is racist, etc. Kipling writes of Gunga Din as 'white, pure white inside' and 'a better man than me!' -- so I know the poem is not racist!

Comment: @EnglishStudent Interesting. Your English is very odd and doesn't seem Indian at all. The way you use the word "Empire" is how Brits use it and not Indians. My guess is, you are pretending to be Indian, defending your precious Empire on an anonymous site. Trust me, it's not worth the trouble.

Comment: @Rahul my friend please do not jump to any hasty conclusions! I was born in India 37 years ago and never travelled outside South India. ALL MY ENGLISH comes from my reading! In fact my spoken English is not so good at all.  I can write English in the way many Indians write it, as in 'Indian English' style, but why? I am Indian only.

Answer (score 28):

There are several good reasons to avoid it as a cultural reference, at least among acquaintances or strangers:

1. It's likely obsolete. The poem and the film are both quite old. Someone for whom the Cary Grant film would have been a normal childhood pop culture experience is around 90 years old now. Other answers indicate that, in the UK, Kipling is studied in less detail than he was in the 1950s and '60s.
2. There's a status implication in the phrase. Gunga Din is subordinate to, and victimized by, the narrator. It's easy for that to come off as paternalistic, or perhaps mocking or sarcastic. (I'd argue, [as T.E.D. does](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/389492/24364), that a semi-sarcastic meaning is perhaps the most natural one.)
3. A highly racialized reference isn't necessarily "innocent" even if you think the original work is. There's a long history of people turning even "positive" portrayals into terms of abuse. Bigots and bullies aren't always particularly educated or choosy: even a muddled reference that still communicates "you are a member of a subaltern group" can serve their purposes just fine.

Getting your meaning across relies on both knowledge and a *rather particular* assumption of good faith from your audience. It's not a phrase that communicates much.

Comment: This is a really good answer... points please? :-)

Comment: "Quite old?"  "Fortune favors the bold.", is old.  I understand your points, though.  I took it to mean that the fellow didn't know or care who Gunga-Din was, not really, until right at the end when he came to his now famous conclusion.

Comment: @ErikBennett A useful distinction is whether you need the context to make sense of the phrase. "Fortune favors the bold" is a self-contained aphorism. You don't need to know its origin to understand the meaning (I tried to look it up and I still don't actually know where its from, to be honest). If I say something about naked woodworking or grains of sand in asafoetida-bearing Cyrene, most people are just going to go, "uhhhh? _what_?" in response. (Bayeux tapestry marginalia and a Catullus poem, respectively, if you're wondering.)

Comment: @Alex P.  I agree.  And for the record, "uhhhh? what?" (regarding your quotes).  I've read that "Fortune favors the bold." is from Thucydides.  'τοῖς τολμῶσιν ἡ τύχη ξύμφορος'... not that I would know;  it's Greek to me.

But, yes.  It seems that to understand the Gunga-Din reference, one would have to read the entire poem.  I tried to speak to that point in one version of my carefully crafted, over edited reply.

Answer (score 19):

I, along with much of my family, use this phrase regularly as a compliment for someone who possesses the fortitude to do something that I doubt I could do. For us, there is never anything insulting either implied or inferred.

Kipling was born and spent his first five years in India, and then lived there again after school from age 16 to 23. For him, the poem was historical. Indians of the lower classes were - much the same as African slaves in America - considered to be something less than human, and were treated as such.

Was such treatment racist? Yes and no. The English treated the lower class Indians like dirt, but then again, so did the upper class Indians. It was expected in that culture. It was not because of his race, but rather his class. The narrator of the poem had every right - even the responsibility - to treat Gunga Din the way he did. To treat him any better would have been considered an insult to the higher classes. Yet at the end of the poem, the speaker acknowledged that Gunga Din was not only in fact a man (not merely lower-class "property"), but that he was even a *better* man than the speaker himself, for Gunga Din possessed courage and character that the speaker did not.

I suppose that one *could* take such a compliment as a sort of insult, but I have never seen it that way. Basically, it is saying "Society may see you as inferior, and I have treated you terribly, but you are truly the better man." It is almost like an apology for not treating someone with the respect that they truly deserve.

Comment: The English also treated many upper-class Indians as dirt. If you have time, visit the Royal Bombay yacht club which has a sign with the wonderful phrase "Dogs and Indians not allowed". It says nothing about class.

Answer (score 19):

This poem is an explicit reference to [the parable of the rich man and Lazarus](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2016:19-31):

> **Givin' drink to poor damned souls**,
>   An' I'll get a swig in hell from Gunga Din!
>   Yes, Din! Din! Din!
>   You **Lazarushian**-leather Gunga Din!

The narrator of the poem puts himself in the place of the rich man in hell who begs for a drop of water from Lazarus (who is **heaven**, the "bosom of Abraham").

In this poem the hyperbole is actually heightened by adding that Gunga Din even comes down to Hell to give a drink to the damned souls (suggesting perhaps not even intentionally that the poet's present state alluded to here is also a kind of hell?), not that Gunga Din is "in hell" as though he belongs there permanently.

So this is pretty well making him out to be as "better as it gets" while sadly never quite removing a little demeaning servitude as Din's "natural" lot.

Within the (severe) limitations of the British post-colonial mentality, it's a perfectly generous compliment, albeit with a heavy serving of irony.

Comment: Many Thanks for weighing in 'with us' on the side of poor departed (and therefore personally defenseless) R.Kipling, who probably wrote the poem with the best of intentions over a 100 years ago, but some modern souls would prefer to 'read' racism into it for their own purposes, whether innocent or devious, and **that** is what is truly prejudiced and distasteful (not because the writing may or may not have been consciously or unconsciously racist, but) for mean-mindedly ignoring the manifest intention and sentiment of the writer as expressed in the context of his works

Comment: Your pointer to the parable of Lazarus (which was amazingly missed by everyone till you drew our attention to it) is also very much appreciated, not only for illuminating our understanding of the context, but also because it suggests the work of an author explicitly alluding to such a noble sentiment is very unlikely indeed to be racist!

Comment: Your interpretation has to be the correct one. Thank you for this; I totally didn't put that together.

Comment: @anongoodnurse OMG! I seem to have won the bounty of 200 points for my answer to this question! A lovely surprise... Thank you so much! I feel honored.

Comment: Actually I think my interpretation is a bit off-topic but at least my answer was short ;-) I think the take-home is that it's just barely a compliment, given the circumstances.

Comment: Thank you for removing my confusion about the ending. It really perfects the entire concept of Gunga Din indeed being the better man.

Comment: I'm not convinced by this. Why do you think Gunga Din is not in hell? *'And I'll meet him later on at the place where he is gone, where it's always double drill and no canteen. He'll be squatting on the coals, giving drinks to poor damned souls, and I'll get a swig in hell from Gunga Din'* Whereas Lazarus *cannot* cross to hell. *between us and you a great chasm has been set in place, so that those who want to go from here to you cannot, nor can anyone cross over from there to us.* So if GD is in hell, he isn't just visiting.

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't dispute the reference to Lazarus, but I don't see how the text of the poem can be made to mesh with the parable and have GD not in hell.

Comment: @Spagirl - yes, that's right, there are some differences and it doesn't appear that Kipling tried very hard to make the poem "mesh" with the parable. I mentioned that that is a difference in my answer and even offered a potential interpretation. Please see above :-)

Comment: @Michael Yes I read your interpretation , but What I'm saying is I don't see any support for it in the text and asking 'why' that is your interpretation.

Comment: Hi @Spagirl ! I think I mentioned that the British mentality has its limitations. This is one of them. The clear divide between beatitude and damnation is removed and the only kind of afterlife one can imagine is a mere continuation of the present life, including social status. I don't think Kipling is trying to make anything mesh with anything, nor to deny anything. It's a reduction of morality to physical comfort which is understandable given the bad conditions obtaining in war.

Comment: @Michael Forgive me, if that answers my question it does so at a level beyond me. Simply, what in the text supports your view that GD isn't really in hell but has popped down from heaven. Why isn't he'll 'the place where he is gone'? I'm not being obtuse, I'm genuinely not following your argument.

Comment: I don't know, it's a poem. Maybe just fit the rythm better?

Answer (score 16):

Well....I think I am a latecomer on this one....but I think context may be the true test of the meaning. I have a personal example....my brother, I am his sister, called me on the phone after my niece who lived with a horrendous disease died at a young age. He said to me in the most sincere way, You are a better man than I, Gunga Din. He was referring to the long years, and the long months leading up to her death of being at her side which he felt he cannot and could not do for anyone. He didn't have what it takes, and he thought I did.

Context....helps.

Comment: Tragic, but excellent example of a very appropriate use of the statement in its right context! Nobody can know your anguish without experiencing it in their own life... What many members here have pointed out is that a specific literary reference such as Gunga Din, particularly when burdened with controversial labels for no good reason, should be used in conversation *only with somebody who we are certain knows the right context and meaning* and will interpret it correctly without taking spurious offense. Thanks a lot for giving us a valuable example of its usage from your personal experience!

Comment: Yeah, this phrase is still current. My dad says it all the time, and I'm not THAT old ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes we analyze too much, resulting in confusion from clarity. I first heard, then read, and later viewed the quotation as a youngster (I am now 75), and to this day I regard it as one of the most introspective and enlightening of all. And with quite positive results as to formative attitudes concerning race.

I am a white man, and if a black person were to say that to or about me, would I consider it anything other than a literate person saying a kind thing? ... I would not.

Natale Chiara

Comment: 1 upvote for this Simplest,  clearest *and nicest* answer!

Comment: There's a lot to be said for clear and simple.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that's no longer considered a compliment is far more likely that the audience is too young, because the modern curriculum has no time for Kipling. I *hope* that's all there is to it.

That is to say, the problem is not what the phrase means or ever meant, but that today's audience simply won't recognise it.

Though the expression of it was and remains racist to an extent shocking to many of us today, it's also of its era and so was and remains complimentary.

Correct me and wasn't Kipling a reporter first, much before a creative author?

Answer (score 1):

I've heard the phrase all my life (born 1948) and my wife (a year older) has, too. My mother (born 1909) used it frequently (a public or parochial school education was a better quality than what you see today).

And, no, Kipling wasn't a racist, any more than Frederic Remington. Kipling was forever paying compliments to Her Majesty's enemies, as in Fuzzy Wuzzy

*WE ’VE fought with many men acrost the seas, 
  An’ some of ’em was brave an’ some was not,

The Paythan an’ the Zulu an’ Burmese;

  But the Fuzzy was the finest o’ the lot.*

Pathan, of course, were the tribesmen of the NorthWest Frontier.

*So ’ere ’s to you, Fuzzy-Wuzzy, at your ’ome in the Soudan;         45
    You ’re a pore benighted ’eathen but a first-class fightin’ man;

    An’ ’ere ’s to you, Fuzzy-Wuzzy, with your ’ayrick ’ead of ’air—

    You big black boundin’ beggar—for you broke a British square!*

Bonaparte couldn't break a British square, but Fuzzy did.

A lot of the epithets against Kipling are the same old Lefty trash thrown at anyone who stands for values. I'll take Kipling over the Antifa, limousine, or any other kind of Liberal any day.

Comment: The Pathan people are still doing well today, mostly living in Pakistan. It's a mark of pride (among themselves!) to be one, they consider themselves brave and honourable and all that sort of thing. They gave the British some shit back in the day.

Answer (score 0):

History and culture is liquid. At it's height, the English Empire was admired by much of the world and their actions were considered upright and justified. Today people look at English colonial beliefs and label them racist and bigoted. At one time Romans looked at the population of Britain and considered them backward. I suppose the Romans were racist and bigoted. Before that (and even at the height of Roman power) your average Greek considered himself superior to the Roman. I guess Classical Greeks were racist and bigoted. Xerxes looked upon the Greeks and thought them rural and mundane. So the Persians were racist and bigoted. The Egyptians tended to consider the Persians as fairly gauche... racist and bigoted Egyptians.

What is and what was are different matters. It depends upon where you stand. Is a fire hot? Your opinion would rather depend on whether you were sitting by a fire or standing in one. I'm sure there will come a time in the future when whatever culture exists will look back on the current "politically correct" movement and murmur "What foolish bigots and self righteous knotheads these people were."

Comment: Well, yes you're right. Racism and xenophobia are not new concepts, both have been around for thousands of years. But more importantly, does this post actually attempt to answer the question?

Comment: A science fiction writer once wrote a poem summarizing Isaac Asimov's famous novel, "Caves of Steel".  The hero, with the help of his robot friend and sidekick, solves the mystery.  The last line of the poem has the hero tell his robot sidekick: "You're a better man that I am, hunk of tin!"

Answer (score 0):

The continued attempt to apply current mores and attitudes about race and morality to times long past is absurd. Every piece of literature is a snapshot of that era. If one is not well read enough to understand the context, any comment is ill informed. I was introduced to Kipling while serving in the military. The poem "The Young British Soldier", opens up a discussion about who benefited from Empire , and who did not. Many a young, poor British lad died on the Afghan plain for the Empire. The British Empire's class system was not so different than the Indian caste system. Those at the top benefited and those at the bottom served. Each system of empire, Greek, Roman, British, Spanish, Japanese, has viewed its subject along these lines. The ruling class, the general citizenry, and the colonial subject were in a social and class hierarchy.

As a sixty-five year old military retiree, I still quote Kipling. It is embedded into the the education and literature of my youth. The knowledge of the context of Kipling's work is what makes quoting him so valuable. It opens up an entire discussion about any empire and the relationship to its subjects and subjugated citizens.

Never reject the knowledge gained by knowing the literature. Always accept that others may have a different viewpoint.

Most honest discussion about empire, race, and class is like Debridement of a third degree burn. Most people don't have the stomach for honest assessment of now versus then. But without the Debridement, the wound never heals.
https://www.poetryloverspage.com/poets/kipling/young_british_soldier.html

Answer (score -3):

I would never have heard of the quote or the poem if I didn't go in for old movies. I enjoyed this one, mostly because the narrator caught me off-guard when he read the last lines of Kipling's poem at the end. I actually got a little misty. I thought it was a beautiful touch that rescued a somewhat far-fetched portrayal of the title role.

Gunga Din was portrayed as a native with boundless admiration for, and puppy-like devotion to, British soldiers and cavalry. Abuse and ridicule had no effect on this admiration. He exhibited so little awareness of his own heritage that his character seemed two-dimensional. In the end, he sacrificed his life blowing a bugle to warn the British of an attack by the irredeemable but elusive Thug tribe, summoning the cavalry just in time to make a climatic charge which, of course, routed the Thugs and put an end to their reign of terror.

Despite the simplicity of Gunga Din's character, the film obviously intended a sympathetic portrayal and not derogatory or derisively comical one. Kipling's lines at the end provided a discernible arc to several roles, infusing the Gunga Din with courage and dignity while imposing unfamiliar humility on the soldiers he admired.

At the risk of sounding judgmental, and given the poem's historical context, it takes a shallow analysis and a prejudicial bias to claim a racist or derogatory intent in either the poem or the movie. As many have already pointed out, ranking people by race was commonplace throughout the world at the end of the 19th century. I would wager a double cheeseburger that it is still common where literacy rates are low. Displaying a tinge of this outdated norm is a poor cause to indict the reputation of a 19th-century poet.

Roping off this quote as inappropriate speech sets a poor precedent; English becomes a minefield and "Gunga Din" becomes another mine in it - the poem lends itself to the conclusion that the memorable final stanza is complimentary to its namesake (see below). There is no reason to presume that borrowing this quote implies or might imply ill intent.

Even if it could be backed by sound reasoning, calling Kipling (or most any deceased person) a racist only provokes an insoluble debate that distracts from more productive conversations about addressing racism.

Despite the lowly status of Kipling's man, his heroic deeds, coupled with the humility expressed by the narrator, oppose the long-standing notion of inherent racial superiority that was still being championed in some academic circles in the late 19th century.

A good case can be made that the poem was bold and very progressive in its time, and that the noted aspects of the final stanza undermine the proposition that Kipling's intent was racist or otherwise unkind when his poem was published.

Given its obscurity the quotation should be applied sparingly, but one does not need to withdraw this quote or feel shame if his/her intent is misunderstood. However, presuming such a quote to be racist or provocative in the absence any corroborating indication of racist intent would be rude. Only the poor defense of ignorance could be persuasively advanced.

Comment: This is a rant, not a serious answer. Malvolio's answer states the essence of what you wrote with much less rancor. You ought to be commenting under the posts with which you disagree, not post a generalized rant like this. I do use the quote to express admiration, and have only seen it used in this way, including recently on a BBC production.

Comment: Welcome rankoutsider, anongoodnurse is quite correct, this is no place for what could be a journalistic opinion piece. Please take the tour: https://english.stackexchange.com/tour and read this about answering: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer